# How long will an already started online Backup with RMAN take?

Tags: oracle, rman

I need to query know how long an online backup which is already started with RMAN will still take.

Any recommendation for a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMAN jobs show up in [V$SESSION_LONGOPS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/V-SESSION_LONGOPS.htm#REFRN30227) with `OPNAME like 'RMAN%'`, there you can query the value of `TIME REMAINING`. Beware, this is just an estimate.